# Jquery - stop mouse-locked position:absolute from extending page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm having some trouble with a cursorhack I've been working on.

On my website, I have a "secret" page, and for reasons, I had to have an animated cursor on that page.

This animated cursor is actually a position:absolute div located within the body, powered by CSS animations. For the most part, this works. I still need to find out how to disable the cursor itself, but it works.

However, whenever I move the mouse to the right/bottom of the viewport, the page starts to extend. this is as the div is an absolute div, so as it goes to the right/bottom, the page extends to allow you to view the part of the cursor that has just left the viewport.

essentially, a position:absolute div located in the body tag is outside the viewport, which is causing issues with the scrollbars extending. naturally, this is not what I want to happen.

is there any way to stop this from happening?

edit: here is the snippet of code I am using, too. in case it helps:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
$("#Cursor").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

Edit2: for a visual reference, this is almost identical to my setup: http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/1/
Try to move the mouse to the bottom/right of the window, and you'll see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `transform` property to [`translate`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#funcdef-translate) the element into the right position – AFAIK “positioning” an element outside the viewport using that should not make the document measurements increase.

If you see to it that your cursor element is positioned at 0/0 to begin with (like by putting
`#Cursor{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}` in your stylesheet), then I think you should be able to just take the `pageX`/`pageY` values as are as translate parameters, like this

```
$("#Cursor").css({
  transform: "translate("+e.pageX+"px, "+e.pageY+"px)"
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's still causing the page to expand. For reference, this is almost identical to my setup: http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/1/

Comment: Hm. Perhaps put the image into a fixed positioned container that stretches the viewport, and has `overflow:hidden` set? http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/2541/ (I used `pointer-events:none` here to stop the container possibly interfering with interaction with the page elements that lay below it – how that fares in older browsers, that don’t support `pointer-events`, you might want to check.)

Comment: That has fixed the problem of the cursor expanding the page, but the new problem is when scrolling downwards, the cursor sorta jumps down beyond your mouse. I think it's messing up with the "+e.pageX+" etc code!

Comment: Ah, that’s right, now that the image is inside the fixed container, its absolute position becomes relative to the container itself. But that can be fixed, if `pageX/-Y` are switched out for `clientX/-Y`, http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/2544/